# Color markers in stripplot by a different variable than hue

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, stripplot

I have made a Seaborn stripplot on top of barplot that has experience group on the axis, grouped by two different conditions (target present or target not present) from a dataframe using the following code:

```
IZ_colors = ['#E1F3DC','#56B567']

ax1 = sns.barplot(data=IZ_df, x='Group', y='Time in IZ (%)', hue='Condition',
                  order=['Std_Ctrl','ELS_Ctrl','Std_CSDS','ELS_CSDS'], hue_order=['Empty','Aggressor'],
                  palette=IZ_colors)

hatches = ['','//']
# Loop over the bars
for bars, hatch in zip(ax1.containers, hatches):
    # Set a different hatch for each group of bars
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_hatch(hatch)
        
            
sns.stripplot(data=IZ_df ,x='Group', y='Time in IZ (%)', hue='Condition', dodge=True,
              order=['Std_Ctrl','ELS_Ctrl','Std_CSDS','ELS_CSDS'], hue_order=['Empty','Aggressor'], 
              palette=IZ_colors, marker='o', size=7, edgecolor='#373737', linewidth=1, color='black',)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.35, 0.7))
```

However, I would like the markers of the stripplot to be colored by sex (not by condition like how they are now), which is another column in the dataframe. I would still like them to be grouped by hue='Condition'. Is this possible?

[image: plot here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two `stripplots`, one for each sex and draw them as the same spot. The double entries of the legend can be removed via `get_legend_handles_labels()` and taking a subset of the handles and the labels.

Here is an example using the titanic dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

IZ_colors = ['#E1F3DC', '#56B567']

ax1 = sns.barplot(data=titanic, x='class', y='age', hue='alive',
                  order=['First', 'Second', 'Third'], hue_order=['no', 'yes'],
                  palette=IZ_colors)

hatches = ['', '//']
for bars, hatch in zip(ax1.containers, hatches):
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_hatch(hatch)
for sex, color in zip(['male', 'female'], ['orange', 'turquoise']):
    df_per_sex = titanic[titanic['sex'] == sex]
    sns.stripplot(data=df_per_sex, x='class', y='age', hue='alive',
                  order=['First', 'Second', 'Third'], hue_order=['no', 'yes'],
                  dodge=True, palette=[color] * 2,
                  marker='o', size=4, edgecolor='#373737', linewidth=1)
handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [handles[0], handles[2]] + handles[4:]
labels = ['Male', 'Female'] + labels[4:]
ax1.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.7), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: stripplot with different colors for non-hue column]